# Do the words of Krishna in the Gita support birth-based caste?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, caste-system, arjuna

this is not a duplicate of

[Does the Bhagavad Gita declare that caste is based on birth?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36408/does-the-bhagavad-gita-declare-that-caste-is-based-on-birth)

in answer to which the words of **Arjuna** are cited:

> 1.41 - When unrighteousness prevails, O Krishna the women of the clan become corrupt; when women become corrupt, there arises intermixture of castes.
>
> adharmābhi-bhavāt kṛṣṇa praduṣyanti kula-striyaḥ | strīṣu duṣṭāsu vārṣṇeya jāyate varṇa-saṅkaraḥ || 41 ||

```
...
```

> 1.43 - By the crimes of the clan-destroyers who bring about intermingling of castes, the ancient traditions of the clan and caste are destroyed.
>
> doṣair etaiḥ kula-ghnānāṁ varṇa-saṅkara-kārakaiḥ | utsādyante jāti-dharmāḥ kula-dharmāśca śāśvatāḥ || 43 ||

This question asks did Krishna, **in his own words**, support birth-based caste.

Because of the infinite ambiguity of Sanskrit,  Swami Mukundananda, denies that even Arjuna was talking about caste:

https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/1/verse/43

> दोषैरेतै: कुलघ्नानां वर्णसङ्करकारकै: |
>   उत्साद्यन्ते जातिधर्मा: कुलधर्माश्च शाश्वता: || 43||
>
> BG 1.43: Through the evil deeds of those who destroy the family tradition and thus give rise to unwanted progeny, a variety of social and family welfare activities are ruined.

This question asks **what Krishna said, in his own words** about birth-based caste.

Comment: Just because you mention it in your question body doesn't change the fact that it is a duplicate.

Comment: And people need to understand that just because they don't find answers to your liking in an existing question they cant post another question with just a basic statement "this is not a duplicate " and only refer to part of the other question to show it is not a duplicate