# What are the consequences of having a Varnashankar child?

Tags: vedas, mahabharata, caste-system, manu-smriti, varna

One verse from Gita says that Varnashankar causes ancestors of a person to fall from heaven to hell for eternity.

Bhagavad Gita 1.42 (Arjun Says)

> Hybrid castes ensure that the family line and those who destroyed the family line, both go to hell. Because their ancestors fall and are deprived of offerings of funereal cakes and drink

What are the other things mentioned about Varnashankars in scriptures ?

There are many examples of Varnashankars in hindu texts , don't know why they are abhorred so much .

Comment: There is no mention of Varna in that verse. If you look at the previous verse it is just generally talking about women being immoral. https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/1/verse/42

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa "Sankro" is written.

Comment: It just seems to be derived from joining. Thus, it can refer to any sex and the resultant children.

Comment: Which is what the translator (not unwarrantedly) did in the linked verse.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa - the previous verse (1.41) explicitly talks about **VARNA**-sankara. And so 1.42 refers to resultant children of such varna-sankara (caste-mixing).

Comment: wrong question , this verse was spoken by arjuna . It shouldn't be part of gita https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36408/does-the-bhagavad-gita-declare-that-caste-is-based-on-birth/38686#38686

Comment: It is very broad. Chapters are dedicated to this. If you want general replications that are applicable for any Sankarya then it can be different. Because some kinds of sankaryas are forbidden and others are allowed.

Comment: In general, It highly depends on the varnas that are undergoing sankarya.

Comment: @hanugm Yeah , I too have heard that certain kind of anulom marriages are allowed , can you enlist which kind of inter-caste marriages is allowed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the Bhagavad Gita declare that caste is based on birth?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36408/does-the-bhagavad-gita-declare-that-caste-is-based-on-birth)

Comment: Yeah @river our site has many questions on it.

Comment: @hanugm Are all kind of anulom marriages allowed ? Or only certain Kind . Parshuram (Kshatriya mother ) and Vedvyas ( Nishad mother) both were Varnashankars.

Comment: @river Vedavyas mother is not nishad by birth.  It is allowed if male is from higher varna and female is from lower varna.

Comment: I will try to share links.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/46175/661

Comment: @hanugm Yes, but Jamadagni married only a Kshatriya woman , then how is Parshuram Brahmin ?